# Use two DjiCodecManager at the same time

Tags: android, dji-sdk

My drone matrice 210.

DJI Android SDK 4.7.1

Device CrystalSky CS785, Android 5.1.1

I shuld display video stream from two camers at the same time, like a DJI Pilot.
My solutions:
I create two diferance DjiCodecManager, and use it in diferent VideoFeeder callbaks.

```
DJICodecManager primaryDJICodecManager  = new DJICodecManager(Activity,
        pramirySurfaceTexture,
        pramirySurfaceTextureTextureWidth,
        pramirySurfaceTextureTextureHeight);

DJICodecManager secondaryDJICodecManager  = new DJICodecManager(Activity,
        secondarySurfaceTexture,
        secondarySurfaceTextureTextureWidth,
        secondarySurfaceTextureTextureHeight);

pramirySurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(new SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
    }
});

secondarySurfaceTexture.setOnFrameAvailableListener(new SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFrameAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        surfaceTexture.updateTexImage();
    }
});

VideoFeeder.VideoFeed videoFeed = VideoFeeder.getInstance().getPrimaryVideoFeed();
VideoFeeder.VideoFeed secondaryVideoFeed = VideoFeeder.getInstance().getSecondaryVideoFeed();

secondaryVideoFeed.setCallback(new VideoFeeder.VideoDataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {
        if (DjiManagers.mSecondaryCodecManager != null) {
            secondaryDJICodecManager.sendDataToDecoder(videoBuffer, size);
        }
    }
});

videoFeed.setCallback(new VideoFeeder.VideoDataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(byte[] videoBuffer, int size) {
        if (DjiManagers.mCodecManager != null) {
            primaryDJICodecManager.sendDataToDecoder(videoBuffer, size);
        }
    }
});
```

But the pramirySurfaceTexture callback does not work. And on the second texture, an image from different cameras (color and grayscale (I use a thermal imaging camera)) appears alternately, but most often the texture is green.

Is it possible to create and use two DJICodecManager?
And if not, how can I show the video stream simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DJI support answered me.

To use two DJICodecManafers. You must use the other constructor:

```
primaryDJICodecManager = new DJICodecManager(Activity,
                    djiSdkWrapper.getSurfaceTexture(),
                    djiSdkWrapper.getSurfaceTextureWidth(),
                    djiSdkWrapper.getSurfaceTextureHeight(),
                    videoStreamSource);
```

where videoStreamSource it's one of this:

```
UsbAccessoryService.VideoStreamSource.Camera
UsbAccessoryService.VideoStreamSource.Fpv
UsbAccessoryService.VideoStreamSource.SecondaryCamera
```

And when you send data to decoding you must use onother *sendDataToDecode* methond:

```
primaryDJICodecManager.sendDataToDecoder(array, size, index);
```

where *intdex* it's one of this:

```
UsbAccessoryService.VideoStreamSource.Camera.getIndex()
UsbAccessoryService.VideoStreamSource.Fpv.getIndex()
UsbAccessoryService.VideoStreamSource.SecondaryCamera.getIndex()
```

In accordance with what you specified when creating DJICodecManager.